# Rails query with latin character

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

On rails 6 with postgres on heroku, I am looking for a simple method to perform a search with or without latin character.

For example: the user enters "gérard" and the query should find all result with "gérard" ou "gèrard"

or

the user enters "gerard" and the query should return result with "gérard", ...

```
 Invoices.where("withoutlatincharacter(name) like ?", "%#{"gérard"}%"))
```

What should I put instead of `withoutlatincharacter`?

Comment: You can replace the characters in Rails with [`transliterate`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58601778/2622934).  You may want to create a column where you use `transliterate` to normalize the data and always save the values without the accented characters.  Or you could run 2 queries, once with the accents and once without.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `unaccent` extension in [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/unaccent.html)

first install the module :

```
CREATE EXTENSION unaccent;
```

then you are good to go , pass your string as it is in ruby and change your sql query to this :

```
... where unaccent(name) like '%' || unaccent('gérard') || '%
```